# Calculate the sum of the elements between the minimum and maximum in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote the following code:

```js
const main = (numbers) => {
    let indexMin = numbers.indexOf(Math.min(...numbers));
    let indexMax = numbers.indexOf(Math.max(...numbers));

    let filter = numbers.slice(indexMin, indexMax, +1);
    let result = filter.splice(1);
    let res = result.reduce((total, n) => total + n, 0);
    return Math.round(res)
};
console.log(main([5, 12, -3, -3, -3, 15, -2, 6, 7]));
```

For this example, the minimum is (the first) `-3` while the maximum is `15`, therefore I want the sum of `[-3, -3]` which works fine.

The problem is that if the index of the maximum element of the array is less than the index of the minimum, e.g. when replacing the `15` with `-15`, then everything breaks down. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple trick you could do is switching the indexes around if they're in the wrong order:

```js
const main = (numbers) => {
  let indexMin = numbers.indexOf(Math.min(...numbers));
  let indexMax = numbers.indexOf(Math.max(...numbers));

  console.log('indexMin:', indexMin);
  console.log('indexMax:', indexMax);

  if (indexMin > indexMax) {
    console.log('Swap!');
    [indexMin, indexMax] = [indexMax, indexMin];
  }

  let filter = numbers.slice(indexMin, indexMax, +1);
  let result = filter.splice(1);
  let res = result.reduce((total, n) => total + n, 0);
  return Math.round(res)
};
console.log(main([5, 12, -3, -3, -3, 15, -2, 6, 7]));
console.log(main([5, 12, -3, -3, -3, -100, -2, 6, 7]));
```

Like you said, the issue is when the maximum element index is lower than the minimum element index. So simply switching them around when needed is a simple but powerful solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent all day trying to find a solution to this problem!